# How to use CV Piano in FL Studio?

Tags: plugins, vst

I have installed CV Piano (by TASCAM), which is in `C:\Program Files\TASCAM\Instruments\CVPiano-GVI-Modeled`, but I want to use it as a VST instrument in FL Studio.

Now FL Studio can only be configured to read VST plugins from one location, which by default is `C:\Program Files\VstPlugins` (and where I have placed a number of plugins already).

How can I use CV Piano in FL Studio (without having to reinstall CV Piano)?

Comment: Is there a DLL file that you could potentially copy into VstPlugins from the installation folder?

Comment: Yes, copying CVPiano-GVI-Modeled.dll to VstPlugins did work. Who thought it would be that simple? Please, answer the question with your suggestion so I can reward you the points.

Comment: One problem might be a difference between 32bit and 64bit plugins! Make sure you are using the one that corresponds to your operating system!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a DLL file in the installation folder, you could copy that into the VstPlugins folder.  I've found this works with some other VST Instruments, such as Synth1.

Copying CVPiano-GVI-Modeled.dll from the installation folder to VstPlugins works in this case.

Comment: I have copied the DLL file and paste on the C:/programfiles/VSTPlugins but I can't find the CVPiano on the FL studio? In which channel is it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you CAN have multiple folders for plug-ins for FL... I have one for 32 bit plugs and one for 64 bit. I believe it's in the FOLDERS section of the options.

Once you've moved the DLL there, you need to refresh FL's plug-in list. Click like you are going to add a VST, but choose "More" (I believe that's the top option). Then a dialog pops up that is a check list of the registered VSTs... you'll need to refresh the list (option on the left side), then check the new plug-in (it'll be in red).

Then you can select it. You have to add an instrument channel, and it will be availible in the list of plug-ins.